# How do I properly call/subset a specific column in a xts object?

Tags: r, subset, xts

I imported some time series data via quantmod and the respective xts object contains several different columns not only one with different prices over time (open close ect). How do I properly call/subset a specific column in a xts object as I need only to work with one of them of further analysis?
getSymbols gets me several price infos per day I dont all need/want.

```
library(quantmod)
data <- getSymbols("GOOGL",src = "yahoo", from = "2000-01-01", to = "2015-01-01")
data <- data[ ,"GOOGL.Open"] #trying to subset like this
data <- data[ , 3] #or this
```

Nothin worked yet. There must be some easy solution. 
Of course I want to preserve the xts structure. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Issue `options(getSymbols.auto.assign = FALSE)` .  Then after running `getSymbols` use `Op(data)`

Answer (score 0):

The object is created in the environment.  We can check `ls()`

```
ls()
#[1] "data"  "GOOGL"
```

If we check `data`, it would be just the character string

```
data
#[1] "GOOGL"
```

and that is the reason it is not working

The object name would be the same symbol name used in `getSymbols`. So, use

```
GOOGL[, "GOOGL.Open"]
```

Or we can `get` the value with

```
get(data)[, "GOOGL.Open"]
```

---

Or if we need to directly assign and wants more control, use the. option `auto.assign = FALSE` as it is by default `TRUE`.  On a fresh `R` session,

```
data <- getSymbols("GOOGL",src = "yahoo", from = "2000-01-01",
        to = "2015-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)

ls()
#[1] "data"
```

as the `auto.assign` is FALSE, it is not creating the GOOGL object.

```
head(data[, "GOOGL.Open"])
#         GOOGL.Open
#2004-08-19   50.05005
#2004-08-20   50.55556
#2004-08-23   55.43043
#2004-08-24   55.67567
#2004-08-25   52.53253
#2004-08-26   52.52753
```

Answer (score 0):

After you run `getSymbols`, the data is present in `GOOGL` and not `data`. Try

```
GOOGL[, "GOOGL.Open"]
GOOGL[, 3]
```